# Amazon SNS Confirmation Token

Tags: spring-mvc, amazon-web-services

I was trying to implement `Amazon SNS` service to my project. I am able to create a topic and subscribe to a topic as well. Here, I am using `sms` as a `protocol` and `phone number`  as `endpoint`. The main problem is I am not getting any confirmation to my mobile phone number and unable to publish message. How can I get a `token` to `confirmSubscription`? `//subscriptionRequest.withToken(token);`

```
 public class SNSServiceImpl implements SNSService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SNSServiceImpl.class);

    @Value("${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:key}")
    private String awsAccessKeyId;
    @Value("${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:secret}")
    private String awsAccessKeySecret;
    @Value("${AWS_REGION:us-west-2}")
    private String awsRegion;

    private AmazonSNS snsClient;
    private String subscriptionArn;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setConnection() {
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsAccessKeySecret);
        AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials);
        snsClient = AmazonSNSClient.builder()
                .withRegion(awsRegion)
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public String createTopic(String topicName) {
        CreateTopicRequest topicRequest = new CreateTopicRequest(topicName);
        CreateTopicResult topicResult = snsClient.createTopic(topicRequest);
        return topicResult.getTopicArn();
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribeToTopic(String topicArn) {
        SubscribeRequest subscribeRequest = new SubscribeRequest();
        subscribeRequest.setTopicArn(topicArn);
        subscribeRequest.setProtocol("sms");
        subscribeRequest.setEndpoint("+14699011920");
        SubscribeResult subscribeResult = snsClient.subscribe(subscribeRequest);

        subscriptionArn = subscribeResult.getSubscriptionArn();
    }

    @Override
    public void confirmSubscription(String topicArn) {

        ConfirmSubscriptionRequest subscriptionRequest = new ConfirmSubscriptionRequest();
        subscriptionRequest.withTopicArn(topicArn);
        //subscriptionRequest.withToken(token);

        ConfirmSubscriptionResult confirmSubscriptionResult = snsClient.confirmSubscription(subscriptionRequest);
        confirmSubscriptionResult.withSubscriptionArn(subscriptionArn);
    }

    @Override
    public void publishMessage(String topicArn, String message) {
        PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest(topicArn, message);
        PublishResult publishResult = snsClient.publish(publishRequest);

        System.out.println(publishResult);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just change the `publishMessage` method and delete the `confirmSubscription` this method from my service.

```
 @Component
public class SNSServiceImpl implements SNSService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SNSServiceImpl.class);

    @Value("${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:key}")
    private String awsAccessKeyId;
    @Value("${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:secret}")
    private String awsAccessKeySecret;
    @Value("${AWS_REGION:us-west-2}")
    private String awsRegion;

    private AmazonSNS snsClient;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setConnection() {
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsAccessKeySecret);
        AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials);
        snsClient = AmazonSNSClient.builder()
                .withRegion(awsRegion)
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public String createTopic(String topicName) {
        CreateTopicRequest topicRequest = new CreateTopicRequest(topicName);
        CreateTopicResult topicResult = snsClient.createTopic(topicRequest);

        logger.info("Create topic request: " + snsClient.getCachedResponseMetadata(topicRequest));
        logger.info("Create topic result: " + topicResult);
        return topicResult.getTopicArn();
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribeSNSToTopic(String topicArn, String phoneNumber) {
        String protocol = "sms";
        SubscribeRequest subscribeRequest = new SubscribeRequest(topicArn, protocol, phoneNumber);
        SubscribeResult subscribeResult = snsClient.subscribe(subscribeRequest);

        logger.info("Subscribe request: " + snsClient.getCachedResponseMetadata(subscribeRequest));
        logger.info("Subscribe result: " + subscribeResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendSMSMessageToTopic(String topicArn, String message) {
        Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes =
                new HashMap<>();
        smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID", new MessageAttributeValue()
                .withStringValue("mySenderID") //The sender ID shown on the device.
                .withDataType("String"));
        smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.MaxPrice", new MessageAttributeValue()
                .withStringValue("0.50") //Sets the max price to 0.50 USD.
                .withDataType("Number"));
        smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType", new MessageAttributeValue()
                .withStringValue("Promotional") //Sets the type to promotional.
                .withDataType("String"));

        PublishResult publishResult = snsClient.publish(new PublishRequest()
                .withTopicArn(topicArn)
                .withMessage(message)
                .withMessageAttributes(smsAttributes));
        logger.info("Public Result: " + publishResult);
    }
}
```